# Not able to get assigned userrole when using external provider to log in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, user-roles

When using an external provider to log in, the assigned userroles are not exposed to the ClaimsPrincipal.

When loggin in using email/local, the user roles are exposed OK.

The call in ExternalLoginCallback:

```
SignInResult signinResult = 
await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
```

When debugging, I see that the CreateAsync method adds the roles, both when using external or email/local login, but when returning to the ExternalLoginCallback, no sign of the roles. What am I missing?

```
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(User user)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var tclaims = user.UserClaims.Select(uc => new Claim(uc.ClaimType, uc.ClaimValue)).ToArray();

                var roleClaims = _userService.GetRolesFromUserId(user.Id);
                
                var allClaims =  tclaims.Concat(roleClaims).ToArray();
                return IdentityServer4.IdentityServerPrincipal.Create(user.Guid, user.UserName, allClaims);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Titti, After external login success, you could try to use [UserManager.AddToRoleAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.addtoroleasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) method to add the specified user to the named role, Then, use [UserManager.GetRolesAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getrolesasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) method to get the a list of role names the specified user belongs to. Then, implement the role based authentication.

Comment: When digging deeper into the code, I finally found what was causing the issue:   
  
After the _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync, there were also an HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Guid, user.UserName, claims.ToArray())  

When replacing the HttpContext.SignInAsync with _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims) it works fine